# How to multiply arrays of different shapes in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to multiply two arrays of two different shapes:

```
np.shape(a) = (20,37,2,121,240)

np.shape(b) = (121,240)
```

I would like to multiply `a*b` where only the values in the two like elements `(121,240)` are multiplied together. The first 3 elements of array "a" `(20,37,2)` will remain the same.

Is there any easier way to do this besides using `for` loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy broadcasts automatically, so you should be able to just do

```
a * b
```

Example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.ones((20,37,2,121,240))

In [3]: b = np.ones(((121,240)))

In [4]: (a * b).shape
Out[4]: (20, 37, 2, 121, 240)
```